# Node js papaparse Empty Results

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, csv, papaparse

What seem to be the issue on the code ? I did follow the implementation from the documentation. Any idea?

## HTML

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:100px;">
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="box login">
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="upload">
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <input type="submit" class="" value="Upload" tabindex="1" style="margin-top:10px;">
            </form>
</div>
```

## Javascript Code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var papa = require('papaparse')

view.on('post', { action: 'upload' }, function (next) {


    var file = fs.createReadStream(req.files.file.path)

    console.log("Request Data :", req.files)

    papa.parse(file, {
        worker: true, // Don't bog down the main thread if its a big file
        step: function(result) {
            // do stuff with result
        },
        complete: function(results, ) {
            console.log('parsing complete read', results); 
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is example of using PapaParser for csv with ','

```
async csvToJson(csvFilePath) {
        let content = fileHelper.fileToString(csvFilePath); // read file to string

        let data = Papa.parse(content, {
            "skipEmptyLines":true,  
            "delimiter":",", 
            "quoteChar": "\""
        });

        return data.data;
    }
```

Comment: I cant find this on the documentation

Comment: try to run this code snippet `Papa.parse(content, {
        "skipEmptyLines":true,  
        "delimiter":",", 
        "quoteChar": "\""
    })`, if it is working for you, then don't care about what documentatin said.

Comment: same results empty results

Comment: I suggest two steps you could do 1. create a new node.js console app to test Papaparser, basically console app will read file into string and let Papaparser convert string into json.

2. use console.log to debug whether file is uploaded successfully or not.